# Add new data in Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery

I am beginner in Jquery. I am using auto complete to suggest data to user in a form text box. Its working properly. But if a user entering a new entry or data in the text box.I need to add that data dynamically to the database by use of a pop up window. After that I need the id of the stored data, for storing the whole form data in other table.

Script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
       var availableTags = <?php include('vname.php'); ?>;
       $("#vessel_name").autocomplete({
       source: availableTags,
       autoFocus:true,
       minLength:2,
       select: function(event, ui) {
       $("#vessel_name").val(ui.item.value);
       $("#vessel_id").val(ui.item.key);
       }
  });
  });
  </script>
```

php:

```
      $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or    die("Error " . mysqli_error($connection));

      //fetch vessel names from the vessel table
      $sql = "select vessel_id,vessel_name from vessel";
      $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error " .       mysqli_error($connection));
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          $vname = $row['vessel_name'];
          $vid = $row['vessel_id'];
          $vname_list[] =array("key"=>"$vid","value"=>"$vname");
      }
      echo json_encode($vname_list);
```

html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Vessel Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="vessel_name" placeholder="Vessel Name" class="form-control" name="nam">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Vessel Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="vessel_id" placeholder="Vessel Name" class="form-control" name="nam">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are doing it right. 
Just grab the stored ***id*** from the form control.

$("#vessel_id").val();
you can as well keep it as an attribute:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function() {
           var availableTags = <?php include('vname.php'); ?>;
           $("#vessel_name").autocomplete({
           source: availableTags,
       autoFocus:true,
       minLength:2,
       select: function(event, ui) {
       $("#vessel_name").val(ui.item.value);
       $("#vessel_id").val(ui.item.key).attr('data-id') = ui.item.key;
       }
  });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Hello @amir the code which I posted  working properly only for autocomplete,  and I am getting data and id correctly. But I need to add new data in autocomplete and need the id of data i have added.

Comment: get the data from DB after saving the id as @WisdmLabs suggested.

Answer (score 0):

In while loop $vid and $vname this value not put in "". It will not enter into your database.

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
          $vname = $row['vessel_name'];
          $vid = $row['vessel_id'];
          $vname_list[] =array("key"=>$vid,"value"=>$vname);
      }
```

Comment: as per the php documentation. echo "$vname"; and echo $vname; are same.